# How can I concat an array to an array that is inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to concat an array to an array (`productsCategories`) inside an array of objects.

So, here's what the `productCategories` array looks like:

```
[
  {
    id: 123,
    items: [ { Obj1 }, { Obj2 } ]
  },
  {
    id:456,
    items: [ { Obj1 }, { Obj2 } ]
  }
]
```

I have some new array, like `[ { Obj3 }, { Obj4 } ]` that I want to `concat` to the `productCategories` for the object where `id = 123`.

So to do this,

I've first used lodash's `find` to find the correct object to update and used `concat` to join the two arrays:

```
let nextItems:any = find(productCategories, { id: payload.id });
nextItems = assign({}, nextItems, { items: nextItems.items.concat(payload.items)});
```

So, `nextItems.items` has the concatenated items array.

However, I am having trouble now adding this to `productCategories` array.  I need to find the object where `id` is the same as `nextItems.id` and then set `productCategories.items` equal to `nextItems.items`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the index of the object that matches the `nextItems.id` in the `productCategories` and assign the new concatenated array to it. You can use the lodash **[findIndex()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findIndex)** method to find the index of the object that matches the id.

```
var index = _findIndex(productCategories, { id: nextItems.id });
productCategories[index].items = nextItems.items;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain JavaScript just as well. With ES6 spread syntax it can look like this:

```
productCategories.filter(x => x.id == payload.id)
                 .forEach(x => x.items.push(...payload.items));
```

Here is a snippet with sample data:

```js
// Sample data
var productCategories = [{
    id: 123,
    items: [ { a: 1 }, { a: 2 } ]
}, {
    id: 456,
    items: [ { b: 1 }, { b: 2 } ]
}];

var payload = {
    id: 123,
    items: [ { c: 1 }, { c: 2 } ]
};

// Update with payload
productCategories.filter(x => x.id == payload.id)
                 .forEach(x => x.items.push(...payload.items));

// Show results
console.log(productCategories);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```